# Setting up Emacs.app on Mac

Tags: emacs, osx-mavericks

So, I can download Emacs.app for Mac from http://emacsformacosx.com/ or I can use brew (see http://struct.tumblr.com/post/46754394733/emacs-24-use-homebrew-instead-of-emacsformacosx).

But how to set up interaction with Finder and so on? Is there a good page detailing this compatible with Mavericks and later versions? (I know little about AppleScript and it seems to have changed with Mavericks).

Comment: What specifically is "interaction with Finder and so on"?  That can mean a million things.  If you associate a file with Emacs, then Emacs will open it.  If you are talking about something more complicated like revealing a file in Finder commencing from `dired-mode` within Emacs, then an Applescript is used.  However, you sound like you are asking a question without having tried anything yet.  Don't be shy -- try it out -- dig in -- make yourself comfortable -- experiment.

Comment: The bit I don't get is how to associate files with emacsclient (so that when I run M-x server-start in Emacs.app and double click files of given types they open new buffers rather than new frames in emacs.app). I can see emacsclient in /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/bin/emacsclient but can't select that in Finder's 'Choose Application' - it is greyed out

Comment: Here is the variable setting which answers the first question -- `emacsclient` is not needed to achieve the effect you seek -- the variable setting goes inside your `.emacs` or `init.el` file:  `(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)`

Comment: As to the second issue, `emacsclient` is normally called from the terminal (not Finder.app).  Since the variable `(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)` achieves your primary goal, perhaps the second issue is moot.